# Can I replace resistor and zener with voltage reference in basic serial regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

The title basically says it all. I wonder if I can use voltage reference like [MAX6043](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max6043.pdf) with NPN BJT to get a simple two-component power source?

For the context, I have a circuit that should draw very little (under 1 mA) power when idle but may need much more than that when active (for driving MOSFET gate). In the current version of the circuit I am using MAX6143 to power 5V comparators and provide 2.5V reference for them at the same time, with total quiescent current only 400uA. The FET gate is driven directly by 30V power bus.

In the next version I'd like to try IGBT instead of MOSFET. But unfortunately the IGBTs typically have 20V gate limit. So the idea is to change all components to 15-16V and use that for driving the gate as well. I am thinking I can use MAX6043 to get very stable sub-mA reference, but add NPN BJT to it as current booster, sufficient for 2.5A rated gate driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The FET gate is driven directly by 30V power bus.

It's pretty rare to see FETs with Vgs rated for this, usually they spec 20V max...

Your gate driver may push 2.5A into the gate, but only during switching. Say your FET has Qg=100nC gate charge (already a large FET) and you switch at F=20kHz, then it's going to use Qg*F=0.002 Coulombs/s, or an average current of only 2mA. You should do the calculation with your circuit parameters, that will give the dissipation in the regulator powering the driver.

Even if average current is low, the driver should not be powered directly from the output of your voltage reference, because the current spikes will cause a lot of ripple and destroy its accuracy.

Most of the gate current spike should come from the driver's decoupling capacitor, and the regulator (or transistor) should not attempt to provide the large current spikes directly, but instead keep the decoupling capacitor charged.

For simplicity, you could keep your current 5V circuit and just use a [high voltage LDO](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7a4101.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1703538986065) for your driver. Or a transistor plus Zener diode. You could also use a buck DC-DC converter, here's a [cheap one with idle current of only 90µA](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP64060.pdf).

Low idle current DC-DC converters spend time in sleep mode then occasionally send a burst of power into the output, which causes ripple. In this case, accuracy of power supply voltage for the driver is irrelevant, it doesn't matter if there's ripple on it, the driver won't care, the MOSFET won't care as long as there's enough voltage get a solid Vgs to turn it on properly.

No on your proposal of boosting the MAX reference chip with a transistor...

In order to check stability with the output capacitor you need to know about the open loop gain and phase vs frequency for the voltage reference, and the datasheet doesn't mention it. It only has output impedance, but that can give hints about the open loop response.

These reference chips are pretty slow, so the transient response is also going to be slow. If you use the transistor-boosted reference to power both the driver and your analog circuits, I'd expect ripple to be rather high, which means it makes no sense anymore to use an expensive, accurate, low drift reference. So I'm not enthusiastic about this option.

Also you'd have to redo your 5V circuit with higher voltage parts which will probably use more idle power.

I'd use either:

- Linear regulator or Transistor+zener to power the driver with about 15V, plus your current circuit
- Or a low quiescent DC-DC to power the driver, then a capacitor multiplier (2 resistors, 10µF MLCC, MMBT3904) as a cheap way to filter this noisy 15V into clean 10V with good PSRR at high frequency... then your existing circuit.

This will also reduce idle power a bit, because the current 400µA idle power will come from the DC-DC, which should have more than 50% efficiency at this current. It also ensures the driver supply is up before the control circuits come up.

Comment: I see. How about third option: "steal" 400uA for logic directly from reference output and use NPN only for gate driver. Then slow reference will be only beneficial to keep logic steady, while the remaining 9mA should be sufficient to keep 300hFE NPN topping up the bypass on the driver. As you said, transients on driver do not matter much, and I think they will not be affecting the reference much

Comment: It should work, if you're paranoid you can always use a darlington or RC filter the voltage to the base of the transistor!

Comment: Oh, I like that. Darlington should isolate the logic power from the gate transients even better. Thank you, I think I'll go with this configuration.

Comment: I'm having hard time finding 15V series reference. But I did find low Iq zener MMSZ4702T1G (50uA) and shunt reference ATL431 (35uA). Can I use these in the same configuration, with logic chips powered directly from transistor base and gate driver from emitter? Specifically, for adjustable reference can I connect top feedback resistor to cathode instead of emitter? I think this will not change the functionality of the circuit, except it will increase stability of logic power and decrease stability of high current load, where it is less important anyway.

Comment: Yes, everything is low voltage now, so good luck finding a 15V reference! Zener has very high temperature coefficient. ATL431 is a shunt regulator, so you'd need to add a transistor to turn it into a series regulator, this often gets unstable depending on how much decoupling capacitance you have on the output. If you do this you'd need to simulate it in spice to check stability. If you don't need accuracy better than a few %, you can simply use a 15V voltage regulator with low idle current.

Comment: Note the capacitance vs stability plots in TL431 datasheet only apply if the cap is across the device, not with a booster transistor. The transistor increases open loop gain, so that changes the stability conditions.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if I can use voltage reference like MAX6043 with NPN BJT to get a simple two-component power source?

Certainly this can be done. Expect that the tempco and load reguation specifications  of the MAX6043 to not be attainable, but might be better than a resistor-zener pair.

The MAX6043 by itself will provide a power source up to 10mA, so can be used alone for durrents up to 10mA as long as power dissipation is properly handled. With the ability to support up to 100μF of load capacitance, the load transients may be well tolerated depending on the application.

2.5A will be challenging for a single transistor buffer. The transistor current gain must be at least 250.

There are many switching regulator solutions that have a low footprint and low component count that are better for high currents.

Comment: I don't think switching regulators can satisfy idle current requirements. Just as zeners they need some current to even begin regulation. Finding BJT with gain more than 250 is not a problem. Interesting comment about capacitance though. I wasn't going to put any  on reference output (transistor base). Should the bypass placed _after_ the NPN be considered somehow in regard to the reference? I was thinking 10-50uF bulk, 1uF on the gate driver and the usual 0.1uF on the comparators

Comment: Also, will the load regulation specs of the reference + BJT combination be worse than reference alone exactly by NPN gain? i.e. the whole 250 times worse?